# How to compare and extract certain items from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There's a list that comprises files' information.

```
tables = ["20180512, name=file01, size=100",
          "20180512, name=file02, size=90",
          "20180513, name=file01, size=70",
          "20180513, name=file02, size=70",
          "20180513, name=file03, size=80",
          "20180514, name=file01, size=100",
          "20180514, name=file02, size=90"]
```

I want to make a dictionary with the biggest item of each day. So, with this list, the dictionary would be

```
dic_table = {20180512:file01,
             20180513:file03,
             20180514:file01}
```

I think I could do this with multiple loops and extra data structures, but I want to know if there are any pythonic ways to efficiently do this job.

Comment: show us what did you try already

Comment: would be great if you shared your initial code so we can have an idea on where to start :)

Comment: Where does this data come from? It feels like this problem should be fixed upstream, not by parsing the strings yourself.

Comment: @timgeb it's actually a pseudo list. The actually data is what I get from a hdf5 file, using walk_nodes.

Comment: @Netwave I was going to, but the actually code depends on other logics and is more complicated than this, so I was worried that it might dilute the purpose of my question. But thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library is perfect for this problem:

First, modify your data so it can easily go in a dataframe, by removing the `size=` and `name=`, as well as unnecessary whitespace:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
tables = [re.sub(r'(\w+=|\s+)', '', i).split(',') for i in tables]

# [['20180512', 'file01', '100'],
# ['20180512', 'file02', '90'],
# ['20180513', 'file01', '70'],
# ['20180513', 'file02', '70'],
# ['20180513', 'file03', '80'],
# ['20180514', 'file01', '100'],
# ['20180514', 'file02', '90']]
```

Then convert to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tables, columns=['Date', 'Name', 'Size'])

#        Date     Name  Size
# 0  20180512   file01   100
# 1  20180512   file02    90
# 2  20180513   file01    70
# 3  20180513   file02    70
# 4  20180513   file03    80
# 5  20180514   file01   100
# 6  20180514   file02    90
```

Finally we can use `groupby` and `idxmax()` to get our maximum values, and `zip` to convert to a dictionary:

```
df['Size'] = df['Size'].astype(int)
maxes = df.iloc[df.groupby('Date').Size.idxmax()]

#           Date    Name  Size
#    0  20180512  file01   100
#    4  20180513  file03    80
#    5  20180514  file01   100

print(dict(zip(maxes.Date.values, maxes.Name.values)))

#  {'20180512': 'file01', '20180513': 'file03', '20180514': 'file01'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Thanks to your detailed explanation, I could easily adopt your example code to the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` from the standard library.

The idea is to sort, group and then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def tupler(x):
    a = x.split(',')
    b = a[1].split('=')[-1]
    c = a[2].split('=')[-1]
    return int(a[0]), b, int(c)

# sort by date and then by size descending
sorter = sorted(map(tupler, tables), key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[2]))

# group by date
grouper = groupby(sorter, key=itemgetter(0))

# extract first item in groups and remove size from result
res = dict(list(j)[0][:-1] for i, j in grouper)

print(res)

{20180512: 'file01',
 20180513: 'file03',
 20180514: 'file01'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've learned useful usages of itertools thanks to you!